# OpenGL GL_POLYGON Not Functioning Properly

Tags: opengl, glsl, polygon, fragment-shader, vertex-buffer

I have an OpenGL-related issue. Whenever I attempt to draw a simple polygon using four vertices from a vertex buffer... nothing happens. However, it will draw the shape in GL_TRIANGLES or GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP mode, albeit distorted. Am I doing something wrong?

Relevent code:

Vertex array: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ybC6.png

GL_POLYGON: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUEJR.png

GL_TRIANGLES: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3imiW.png

GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Qfu.png

Comment: Why are you using polygons in the first place? In OpenGL polygons must be convex, which is quite limiting. Hence polygons have been removed from later versions of OpenGL alltogether (also quads). Stick with triangles and don't care about polygons in the first place.

Comment: ...Then is that why it doesn't draw in polygon mode? I'm using a forward-compatible 3.2 core profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using a forward-compatible 3.2 core profile

First of all, *never* use a "forward-compatible core profile". You should just use a core profile; stop using the forward compatibility bit. It's pointless.

More importantly, `GL_POLYGON` is not part of a core OpenGL profile. It was [removed in 3.1.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL#Deprecation_Model) So your code is likely giving you a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error that you're ignoring.

Lastly, always post your OpenGL version and profile in your question.