# Dedicated Nvidia GPU won't draw OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

My setup includes on-board Intel integrated GPU for everyday tasks and a high-performance Nvidia GPU for graphics-intensive applications. I'm developing an OpenGL 3.3 (core profile) application (using shaders, not fixed-function-pipeline). By default, my app runs on Intel GPU and works just fine. But should I try to run it on Nvidia, it only shows the black screen.

Now here's the interesting part. OpenGL context gets loaded correctly, and world coordinate axes I draw for debugging actually get drawn (`GL_LINE`). For some reason, Nvidia doesn't draw any `GL_POLYGON`s or `GL_QUAD`s.

Has anyone experienced something similar, and what do you think is the culprit here?

Comment: Are you using a core profile? - see [OpenGL GL_POLYGON Not Functioning Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762257/opengl-gl-polygon-not-functioning-properly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenGL GL\_POLYGON Not Functioning Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762257/opengl-gl-polygon-not-functioning-properly)

Comment: I am using core-profile OpenGL 3.3. I didn't set forward compatibility bit.

Comment: It appears GL_POLYGON, GL_QUADS and GL_QUAD_STRIP are deprecated in OpenGL 3.3 core profile. For some reason Intel draws them regardless, but Nvidia started drawing as well, as soon as I substituted those with GL_TRIANGLES etc. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It appears `GL_POLYGON`, `GL_QUADS` and `GL_QUAD_STRIP` are removed from OpenGL 3.3 core profile. For some reason Intel draws them regardless, but Nvidia started drawing as well, as soon as I substituted those with `GL_TRIANGLES` etc. Always check for removed features if problems like this arise.

Comment: Unless the driver reports an error (glGetError() == GL_INVALID_XXX) when using deprecated functions it is still a bug.